# Using Redux Form with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux, redux-form

I've been spinning my wheels for a while now trying to figure out the best way to do all of this. Here is my situation:

I'm using a mix of React Router and Redux Form to create login/create account pages.

```
export default (
  <Route path='/' component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Signup} />
    <Route path='signup_verify' component={SignupVerify} />
  </Route>    
);
```

When you load the homepage it shows the fields to create an account

[image]

I use React Form to validate the fields and once everything is ok I do

```
onSubmit() {
  this.context.router.push('/signup_verify')
}
```

thus pushing them to the next and last page of the wizard. In this second page I have a disabled input that I want to populate with the name they gave me in the prior form. **How the heck do I get the name the user submitted to appear in this second page?**

React Form talks about using decorators:

```
@reduxForm({
  form: 'myForm'
})
```

http://redux-form.com/5.2.4/#/api/get-values?_k=eo04uv

https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/260#issuecomment-155852315

I set up my environment to be able to use decorators but when I try to implement the same code a few lines above I an error saying:

Warning.js:45Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop `fields` of type `object` supplied to `ReduxForm(Signup)`, expected an array. Check the render method of `Connect(ReduxForm(Signup))`.warning @ warning.js:45
getValues.js:59

and

Uncaught TypeError: fields.reduce is not a function

My first page, where the screenshot came from, looks VERY similar to *WizardFormFirstPage.js* (http://redux-form.com/5.2.4/#/examples/wizard?_k=y8mg56). **How would WizardFormSecondPage display data from WizardFormFirstPage in a disabled input?**

I know that's a lot, any help is greatly appreciated! Also any feedback on doing this another way would be awesome, or thumbs up on my current approach.

Answer (score 2):

Set the option `destroyOnUnmount: false` in your `reduxForm()` decorator.

Secondly, you should probably use the `react-redux` package. It has a function called `connect()` which allows you to pass state to the props.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    name: state.form.myForm.name,
    email: state.form.myForm.email,
    company: state.form.myForm.company
  }
};

const SignupVerify = connect(mapStateToProps)(SignupVerify)
```

Replace `SignupVerify` with the name of your component.

`state.form.myForm` will change depending on what properties you entered for `reduxForm()`

[Redux usage with React](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html)

[Redux-Form wizard example](http://redux-form.com/6.1.1/examples/wizard/)

Answer (score 0):

After a few console logs I found out that the input value from the first page will survive to the next page IF:

1) Export all of your fields on the first page, or at least the one you want to access. IE:

export const fields = ['name', 'email', 'company'];

2) Specify the destroyOnUnmount: false flag to preserve form data across form component unmounts.

3) Pull it off of props in your next page from the wizard. IE:
const {fields: {name}, handleSubmit} = this.props;

Then you will have access to it under thing.value. IE:

name.value will equal whatever I put into the name input on the first page.

Docs for more info: http://redux-form.com/5.2.4/#/examples/wizard?_k=y8mg56